# How can I put a DataGridTextColumn or DataGridComboBoxColumn inside of a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a column in a `DataGrid` that needs to display both textboxes and comboboxes conditionally. To do this, I used a `DataTemplate`. However, normal `TextBox` and `ComboBox` elements do not act the same way as `DataGridTextColumn` and `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. For example, I want to be able to press `Enter` and it skip to the next cell. This is not working with a normal `TextBox`.

Is there a way to put a `DataGridTextColumn` or `DataGridComboBoxColumn` inside of a `DataTemplate`. Or is there a way to make a `TextBox` appear as a `DataGridTextColumn` or `ComboBox` as a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`?

I am trying to accomplish something like the following:

```cs
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SetupData}" Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Binding="{Binding SetupComboboxData}" Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

I receive this error: `The root of a Template content section cannot contain an element of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn'. Only FrameworkElement and FrameworkContentElement types are valid.`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to put a DataGridTextColumn or DataGridComboBoxColumn inside of a DataTemplate?

No.

> Or is there a way to make a TextBox appear as a DataGridTextColumn or ComboBox as a DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Yes. Define the text column like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SetupData}" Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SetupData}" Foreground="DodgerBlue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And in the `ComboBox` column you put a `ComboBox` in the `CellEditingTemplate` template instead of a `TextBox`.

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple types in one column

Comment: What do you mean? You will obviously have to switch templates.